# Finding heap corruption reason with Application Verifier

Tags: c++, clion, heap-corruption, application-verifier

I'm having some issues with my C++ application.
When I use Clion's debugger - everything works great.
but whe I take the compiled executable (under windows) and try to run it *with the same input file* as I did in debugging mode - the application crush.
since I cant find the crush reason in dubugging - some search in the internet got me to find the Application Verifier tool by microsoft.

It can diagnoze the crash + show the stacktrace but my problem is that I can't convert the names in the stacktrace to method names in c++

this is the error part (my app name is gridSolver):

```
    <avrf:logEntry Time="2017-03-30 : 02:52:53" LayerName="Heaps" StopCode="0x13" Severity="Error">
        <avrf:message>First chance access violation for current stack trace.</avrf:message>
        <avrf:parameter1>7838000 - Invalid address causing the exception.</avrf:parameter1>
        <avrf:parameter2>7fefe9f1151 - Code address executing the invalid access.</avrf:parameter2>
        <avrf:parameter3>2280b0 - Exception record.</avrf:parameter3>
        <avrf:parameter4>227bc0 - Context record.</avrf:parameter4>
        <avrf:stackTrace>
            <avrf:trace>vrfcore!VerifierDisableVerifier+950 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
            <avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlApplicationVerifierStop+d3 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
            <avrf:trace>vfbasics!+7fed38d26c5 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
            <avrf:trace>vfbasics!+7fed38d4606 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
            <avrf:trace>vfbasics!+7fed38d3c4a ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
            <avrf:trace>ntdll!vsprintf_s+12b ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
            <avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlUnwindEx+852 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
            <avrf:trace>ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+2e ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
            <avrf:trace>msvcrt!memcpy+71 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
            <avrf:trace>gridSolver!+4314fa ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
            <avrf:trace>gridSolver!+43171c ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
            <avrf:trace>gridSolver!+44bb29 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
            <avrf:trace>gridSolver!+420a85 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
            <avrf:trace>gridSolver!+402e4b ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
            <avrf:trace>gridSolver!+4013b5 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
            <avrf:trace>gridSolver!+4014e8 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
            <avrf:trace>KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+d ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
            <avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+21 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
        </avrf:stackTrace>
    </avrf:logEntry>
```

Can please someone assist?
maybe there is an other way to solve this issue?

Comment: Could it be that it only crashes in Release configuration and you try to debug it in a Debug build configuration?

Comment: Likely what @zneak said. Your application could crash in the release build for a number of reasons. I'd recommend that you read this very informative article: http://www.flounder.com/debug_release.htm

Comment: You can run your application under debugger with Application Verifier enabled so this bug will trigger a debug break instead of killing process immediately. Note that if you are running a release build you need to make sure that debug information generation is enabled so you will receive a readable call stack and can inspect some variables.